# Adding Listeners to JButtons

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to add ActionListeners to JButtons `New`, `Delete` and `Search`. 
I've tried several things and ways but still cannot get this work.

P.S I've added action to button `New`, seems to work but it does not add anything in array.

Every help is appreciated! Thanks in advance.

```
package datingrun;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Main extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Onomata");

        JLabel ll = new JLabel("Êáôá÷ùñÞóåéò");
        ll.setBounds(150, 20, 300, 15);

        JLabel l2 = new JLabel("Onoma");
        l2.setBounds(155, 80, 300, 15);

        JLabel l3 = new JLabel("Filo");
        l3.setBounds(270, 80, 100, 15);

        JLabel l4 = new JLabel("Ilikia");
        l4.setBounds(280, 80, 100, 15);

        JButton b1 = new JButton();
        b1.setText("New");
        b1.setBounds(105, 400, 80, 40);



        JButton b2 = new JButton();
        b2.setText("Search");
        b2.setBounds(205, 400, 80, 40);



        JButton b3 = new JButton();
        b3.setText("Delete");
        b3.setBounds(305, 400, 80, 40);



        JTextField tf1 = new JTextField(20);
        tf1.setSize(15, 20);
        tf1.setBounds(130, 100, 100, 20);

        JTextField tf2 = new JTextField(20);
        tf2.setSize(15, 20);
        tf2.setBounds(250, 100, 100, 20);

        JTextArea t1 = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
        t1.setColumns(20);
        t1.setRows(5);
        t1.setEditable(false);
        t1.setBounds(125, 200, 120, 150);

        JTextArea t2 = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
        t2.setColumns(20);
        t2.setRows(5);
        t2.setEditable(false);
        t2.setBounds(245, 200, 120, 150);

        JTextArea t3 = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
        t3.setColumns(30);
        t3.setRows(5);
        t3.setEditable(false);
        t3.setBounds(245, 220, 100, 100);

        frame.add(ll);
        frame.add(l2);
        frame.add(l3);
        frame.add(tf1);
        frame.add(tf2);
        frame.add(t1);
        frame.add(t2);
        frame.add(t3);
        frame.add(b1);
        frame.add(b2);
        frame.add(b3);

        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setLayout(null);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        final ArrayList Onomata = new ArrayList();

        Onomata.add("Stelios Mavridis");
        Onomata.add("Nikos Tzouvelekis");
        Onomata.add("Andreas Paraskevas");

        final ArrayList Filo = new ArrayList();

        Filo.add("M");
        Filo.add("M");
        Filo.add("M");

        final ArrayList Ilikia = new ArrayList();

        Ilikia.add("24");
        Ilikia.add("30");
        Ilikia.add("40");

        t1.append("Onoma \n");
        t2.append("Filo \n");
        t3.append("Ilikia \n");

        for (int i = 0; i < Onomata.size() && i < Filo.size() && i < Ilikia.size(); i++) {
            t1.append((String) Onomata.get(i) + "\n");
            t2.append((String) Filo.get(i) + "\n");
            t3.append(Ilikia.get(i).toString() + "\n");



        }
        b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                String text = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Insert");
                String item = null;

                if (text != null) {
                    item = text.trim();
                } else {
                    return;
                }

                if (!item.isEmpty()) {
                    Onomata.add(item);
                    Filo.add(item);
                    Ilikia.add(item);
                }
            }
        });


    }
}
```

Comment: Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify

Answer (score 3):

Start by having a look at [How to Write an Action Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html).

Since you've successfully got an `ActionListener` registered with the `JButton`, we can assume that problem is solved.

After testing your code, `item` is been added to your `ArrayList`s, you're just not updating the UI with the new content, maybe something like...

```
b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        String text = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Insert");
        String item = null;

        if (text != null) {
            item = text.trim();
        } else {
            return;
        }

        if (!item.isEmpty()) {
            Onomata.add(item);
            Filo.add(item);
            Ilikia.add(item);
            t1.setText(null);
            t2.setText(null);
            t3.setText(null);
            for (int i = 0; i < Onomata.size() && i < Filo.size() && i < Ilikia.size(); i++) {
                t1.append((String) Onomata.get(i) + "\n");
                t2.append((String) Filo.get(i) + "\n");
                t3.append(Ilikia.get(i).toString() + "\n");

            }
        }
    }
});
```

Now, having run the code, `JTextArea` is not well suited to the task you seem to be trying to complete, instead, maybe consider using a `JTable`, see [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for more details.

Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify

See [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for more details

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick response!but i have one more problem regarding JTextArea3 where is supposed ArrayList "Ilikia" should be displayed...but when i run the program,it is not displayed there...can you help me out with this?i don't think i am missing something but  do not know what is going on

Comment: You need to run all of the GUI stuff on the event thread, which you are not doing.

Comment: Use a layout manager, null layouts are going to give you so many head aches. As I said, what you seem to be doing isn't the best idea, instead, you need to use something like a `JTable`